# Solving Summation Expression

Tags: calculus, summation

I was having some error calculating this question. I was wondering if anyone could help me out!

Solve for x:

$\sum_{n=1}^\infty 3x^{5n} = 27$

Comment: Please, show your ideas on this problem.

Comment: Begin by having a look at geometric series.

Comment: **Hint:** Let $r=x^5$.  Then you have $\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty 3x^{5n} = 3\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty r^n$.  The summation here should be very familiar and you should be able to evaluate it.  Now, set the result equal to $27$ and perform a bit of algebra to reach a final conclusion about the value of $x$.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}3x^{5n}=3\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}(x^5)^n=\frac{3x^5}{1-x^5}$$ for all $|x|<1$ (otherwise the series diverges). Thus
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}3x^{5n}=27\iff x^5=9(1-x^5)\iff x=\left(\frac{9}{10}\right)^{1/5} $$